# Why am I getting the error 'Unknown or uninitialised column: `x`. ' in R?

Tags: r, function, unique, custom-function

As part of a larger function, I'm trying to extract unique, non-na values, so I can iterate over that list. In this function, users should be able to input any column name that exists in their dataframe.

In the past, when I've had to convert a user input into a string, `x_character <- deparse(substitute(x))` has worked. However, now I get NULL as my output of the below function with the warning of `1: Unknown or uninitialised column: x`.

Why is R not recognizing this x_character with the $ operator? It's worked in the past, so I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong here.

```
#Sample data
library(dplyr)
my_data <- tibble(level = c(rep(c("1st", "2nd", NA, "3rd"), 4), NA, "2nd"),
                  id = c(1:17, 30),
                  score = c(81:97, 70))
```

And here's my code:

```
unique_without_na <- function(data, x) {
  #Pulls out all rows with data in the cut_by argument; drops nas
  x_character <- deparse(substitute(x))
  print(x_character) #just a check
  
  unique_x <- data$x_character[!is.na(data$x_character)] %>% unique()
  unique_x
  
}

unique_without_na(my_data, level) #doesn't work; I've also tried "level" which also fails
unique_without_na(my_data, score) #also doesn't work
```

Comment: You are using `$` wrong. You could use `[[` instead. I.e. `data[[x_character]]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put them in `[[` instead of using `$`

```
unique_without_na <- function(data, x) {
  #Pulls out all rows with data in the cut_by argument; drops nas
  x_character <- deparse(substitute(x))
  print(x_character) #just a check
  
  unique_x <- data[[x_character]][!is.na(data[[x_character]])] %>% unique()
  unique_x
  
}

unique_without_na(my_data, level)
#> [1] "level"
#> [1] "1st" "2nd" "3rd"
unique_without_na(my_data, score) 
#> [1] "score"
#>  [1] 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 70
```

Comment: thank you! Can you explain why it needs the [[]]] and what that means? I'll accept the answer in 9 minutes when SO lets me

Comment: See here <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169456/the-difference-between-bracket-and-double-bracket-for-accessing-the-el>

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively with `expr` and `eval` we could try something below.
here we can use `$` instead of `[[`

```r
library(rlang)
library(dplyr)

unique_without_na <- function(data, x) {
  #Pulls out all rows with data in the cut_by argument; drops nas
  x_character <- deparse(substitute(x))
  print(x_character) #just a check
  
  unique_x <- eval(expr('$'(data,!!x_character)))[!is.na(eval(expr('$'(data,!!x_character))))] %>% unique()
  unique_x
  
}
unique_without_na(my_data, level)
#> [1] "level"
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-20 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

### output

```r
[1] "1st" "2nd" "3rd"
```